# Переход на другое Activity из SearchView

Tags: java, android

Есть SearchView в который выводятся значения из базы данных. Как установить обработчик нажатия на значения, которые выводит SearchView, чтобы, например, перейти на Activity этого значения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Main Activity**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        activateSearchView(menu);
        return true;
    }

private void activateSearchView(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService
            (Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class)));
}
```

**Database Helper**

```
 public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
    return myDataBase.query("NATURE_TABLE", null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
public ArrayList<String> getAllEmployeesName(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> employeesNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("NATURE_TABLE",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do{
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            employeesNames.add(name);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return employeesNames;
}
```

**ProviderActivity**

```
public class ProviderActivity extends ContentProvider {

DatabaseHelper myDB;
ArrayList<String> employees;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    return false;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strings, String s, String[] strings1, String s1) {

    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

    String employeeName;
    employees = myDB.getAllEmployeesName();

    MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{
            BaseColumns._ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID
    });

    if(employees != null){
        String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toString();
        int limit = Integer.parseInt(uri.getQueryParameter
                (SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT));

        int length = employees.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < length && matrixCursor.getCount() < limit; i++) {
            String employee = employees.get(i);

            if(employee.contains(query)) {
                matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{i, employee, i});

            }
        }

    }
    return matrixCursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String s, String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно для разных поисковых строк переходить на разные активити или в одну и ту же передавать, что выбрано при поиске? Что дальше происходит, когда в поиске что то выбрано?

Comment: Для каждой строки своё активити. То есть,  я ищу "Глаз", нахожу и мне надо перейти на активити Глаза - EyesActivity. @pavlofff

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял, то так:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Так же вот [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnSearchClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) на документацию

Comment: Для каждой записи нужно переходить на свою активити, а не на одну для всех

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы дали код, в котором при выборе любого результата в SearchView перекидывает на второе активити. Но мне надо, чтобы был переход на активити того значения, которое я нашел в SearchView. Например, выше у меня есть скрин, где я ввожу в SeachVIew "Глаз", он его находит по  базе данных, и мне надо перейти по нажатию на строку с "Глазом", которую нашел SeacrView, на активити Глаза, например, EyesActivity и так дальше, нахожу Мозг, нажимаю на него и меня должно перекидывать на BrainActivity.

Comment: Но так вы можете передавать данные в другую `Activity` с помощью `putExtra`. Я ведь как понимаю, `layout` второго `activity` типичен для вывода информации ? Если нет, тогда можно разделить все результаты поиска по определенным группам, а далее уже через `switch` работать с ними. Вопрос ведь не встает в дизайне и расположении контролов, как я понимаю, а вопрос заключается в способе вывода информации.